# VB.NET - Ошибка при записи данных в файл

Tags: vb.net

Вот есть код:

```
Dim Link, FileName, aa, bb
Link = TextBox1.Text
FileName = TextBox2.Text

Link = TextEncrypt(Link)
FileName = TextEncrypt(FileName)

If IO.File.Exists("data.dat") Then
    IO.File.Delete("data.dat")
    IO.File.Create("data.dat")
End If

aa = Link + Environment.NewLine
bb = FileName + Environment.NewLine
IO.File.WriteAllText("data.dat", aa)
IO.File.AppendAllText("data.dat", bb)
MsgBox("The data file was created successfully!")
Application.Exit()
```

Результатом является ошибка о том что "Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу так как этот файл используется другим процессом."
Знаю вопрос глуп. Но как быть?
Я что то забыл? Или я чего то не знаю?

Comment: Ну, во-первых, если файл есть, Вы его удаляете и создаёте новый. А если его нет - то так и нет. Уже косяк. Во-вторых, при создании файла он открывается и таковым остаётся. И Вы не сохраняете его хэндл - как Вы собираетесь в него писАть? В третьих, File.Create, равно как и File.WriteAllText - просто перезапишут существующий файл, так что никакие проверки и удаления вообще не нужны. *я чего то не знаю?* Вероятно... почитайте https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx и https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx , и посмотрите там же примеры для VB.

Comment: Уже разобрался, но все равно благодарю за ответ. :)